# how to set autoincremental Id in a table and add data

Tags: c#, sql

**How to do it in Visual Studio?** I've set Autoincrement = true in dataset design and set "YES" in identity specifications in database diagram. What else?

**But how to add data now?** When I'm trying to do like this but I've got an exception.
The code.

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Subject" +
                " Values (namesubject,numberoflect,numberofpract)", conn);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            //param.ParameterName = "@idsubject";
            //param.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            //param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            //param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "namesubject";
            param.Value = textBox2.Text;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "numberoflect";
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
                textBox3.Text = "0";
            param.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "numberofpract";
            if (textBox4.Text == "")
                textBox4.Text = "0";
            param.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Autoincremental field - idsubject in this table.

Answer (score 2):

first of all Set Auto identity of idsubject to true

OR

```
 Create table ....
(
   idsubject int Auto identity (1,1) not null
   ....
   ....
)
```

and modify your insert code like

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Subject(namesubject, numberoflect, numberofpract)" +
            " Values ('"+textBox2.Text+"',"+textBox3.Text+","+textBox3.Text+")", conn);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```